# Kotlin Pass in a type that implements a parameterized interface

Tags: java, android, types, kotlin

i have the following working Java code however when i convert it into Kotlin, the code does not compile

**Java** code

```
public interface Presenter<V> {
   void attachView(V view);
}
```

Abstract class implementing above interface

```
public abstract class BasePresenter<T> implements Presenter<T> {
    @Override
    public void attachView(T view) {
        this.view = view;
    }
}
```

Abstract class that takes a Type parameter which implements the interface above

```
public abstract class PresenterActivity<P extends Presenter> extends BaseActivity {

    protected P presenter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (presenter != null) {
        presenter.attachView(this);
        }
    }
}
```

A class extending BasePresenter

```
public class FooPresenter extends BasePresenter<BarView> {
    ...
}
```

A class extending PresenterActivity

```
public class SomeActivity extends PresenterActivity<FooPresenter> implements BarView {
   ....
}
```

**Kotlin** code converted from above Java Code

```
interface Presenter<in V> {
    fun attachView(view: V)
}
```

Abstract class implementing above interface

```
abstract class BasePresenter<V> : Presenter<V> {
    override fun attachView(view: V) {
        this.view = view
    }
}
```

Abstract class that takes a Type parameter which implements the interface above, am not sure if `<P : Presenter<Any>>` below, is the correct expression

```
abstract class PresenterActivity<P : Presenter<Any>> : BaseActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        if (presenter != null) {
            presenter!!.attachView(this)
        }
   }
}
```

A class extending BasePresenter

```
class FooPresenter : BasePresenter<BarView>() {
    ....
}
```

A class extending PresenterActivity

```
class SomeActivity : PresenterActivity<FooPresenter>(), BarView {
    ....
}
```

The Kotlin class `PresenterActivity` gives the following compilation error
Error:(9, 44) Type argument is not within its bounds: should be sub-type of '`Presenter<Any>`'

this means `FooPresenter` is not recorgnised as a sub-type of `Presenter<Any>`

am assuming `Presenter<V>` is a subclass of `Presenter<Any>`, i have a feeling am wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Java code actually has a type safety problem: `PresenterActivity<P extends Presenter>` uses a [raw type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html) and when you later write `presenter.attachView(this)` you don't know whether you *can* attach `this`, but raw type means the compiler doesn't warn you. Kotlin doesn't let you hide it like this.

> am assuming `Presenter<V>` is a subclass of `Presenter<Any>`, i have a feeling am wrong

`in` actually means `Presenter<V>` is a *super*-type of `Presenter<Any>`, not a subtype. See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html (or search for covariance and contravariance, there are a lot of explanations on Stack Overflow and otherwise, though more for Scala than Kotlin but the idea is the same).

I think the simplest solution would be something like

```
// concrete subclasses must extend V
abstract class PresenterActivity<V, P : Presenter<V>> : BaseActivity() {
   ... presenter!!.attachView(this as V)
}
```

and

```
class SomeActivity : PresenterActivity<BarView, FooPresenter>(), BarView {
    ....
}
```